# Use of NDSolve in loops

Tags: differential-equations, procedural-programming

Im new to mathematica and have some problems to use NDSolve in a loop (at least i suspect this is the reason for my problems). I hope anybody can help me! Thanks a lot in advance!
I created the following code block, which works just fine so far. 
But now i want to put the last code block into a loop and vary UL from 0 to 1.2 with steps of 0.1. I already tried it with a Do loop, but then i get loads of warnings such as 'ReplaceAll::reps: "{s} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing'. I also tried it with a Table, but i couldn't the right syntax there too. At the end, i'd like to plot all the Un and j-Values against each other. How would you code this?

```
(*Input parameters*)
     UL = 0.8; nC = 0.00205498; nH = 0.0164398; nO = 0.00410996; nN = 0;
     Kp1 = 1.0853; Kp2 = 1.503*10^(9); ASRRU = (0.3/10000); p = 100000; 
     R = 8.3144598; h = 0.00055 ; T = 800 + 273; tau = 0.2; F = 96485.33289

(*Function*)
       nO2[x_] = ((2 nC + nH + nN) (2 nC - 4 Kp1 nC - nH - 2 x + 2 Kp1 x + \[Sqrt](8 (-1 + Kp1) nC (4 nC + nH -2 x) + ((6 - 4 Kp1) nC + nH + 2 (-1 + Kp1) x)^2))^2)/(2 Kp2^2 (2 nC - 4 Kp1 nC + nH - 2 Kp1 nH - 2 x + 2 Kp1 x + \[Sqrt](8 (-1 + Kp1) nC (4 nC + nH - 2 x) + ((6 - 4 Kp1) nC + nH + 2 (-1 + Kp1) x)^2))^2 p)

(*Codeblock for loop*)    
    s = NDSolve[{NO'[
         t] == (1/(2*F*
             ASRRU))*(((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - 
              Log[(nO2[NO[t]] *(R*T))/h]) - UL), NO[0] == nO}, 
      NO, {t, 0, 100}]
    Plot[Evaluate[NO[t] /. s], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
    Evaluate[NO[0.2] /. s]
    UN1[t_] = ((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - 
        Log[(nO2[Evaluate[NO[t] /. s]]*(R*T))/h])
    j[t_] = (UN1[t] - UL)/(ASRRU *10000)
    Un = NIntegrate[UN1[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau
    J = NIntegrate[j[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau
```

Comment: I recommend you look up `ParametricNDSolve` and try to rephrase your problem in such a way that you can use that. That would give you a lot more functionality than simply varying `UL` through a bunch of values.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd Smit. I will keep your recommendation in mind! For no use the Map command, but at a later point it might be useful to switch to ParametricNDSolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need to put it in a loop. *Mathematica* has many other cleaner/faster/shorter ways of implementing this kind of thing. I'll give you three:

1. A `Do` loop (which you asked for, so it wouldn't be much of an answer if I didn't).
2. An alternative using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (or `/@`), which shows up all over the place and is probably one of the most useful *Mathematica* functions.
3. A method using [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html), as suggested by @SjoerdSmit in comments, which is probably the way that a problem like this should be tackled.

**A `Do` Loop**

Here's a quick and dirty loopification of your code:

```
points = Last@Last@Reap@Do[
     s = NDSolve[{NO'[t] == 
         (1/(2*F*ASRRU))*(((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[NO[t]]*(R*T))/h]) - UL), 
       NO[0] == nO}, NO, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1]];

     UN1[t_] = ((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[Evaluate[NO[t] /. s]]*(R*T))/h]);
     j[t_] = (UN1[t] - UL)/(ASRRU*10000);

     Sow[{NIntegrate[j[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau, NIntegrate[UN1[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau}],
    {UL, 0, 1.2, 0.1}]

ListPlot[points, AxesLabel -> {"j", "UN1"}]
```

All I've really done is put semicolons in, taken out your `Plot`, `Flatten`ed `s`, and added [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) to accumulate the results of the loop. It could definitely be improved, but I think that's something like what you were going for.

**Using `Map` over a list of parameter values**

*Mathematica* makes it nice and easy just use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), or `/@`, and run everything over lists. (If you're not familiar with what `f[#] & /@ list` means, really check out the docs on `Map` and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) -- all it does is apply the function `f` to each element of `list` and give you back the transformed list).

To start off, get whatever range of parameters you're interested in:

```
ULrange = Range[0, 1.2, 0.1];
```

Then you can just `Map` your `NDSolve` over that:

```
s = NDSolve[{NO'[t] == 
    (1/(2*F*ASRRU))*(((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[NO[t]]*(R*T))/h]) - #), 
  NO[0] == nO}, NO, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1]] & /@ ULrange;
```

In this case, `s` is now a vector of solutions for each of the different values of `UL`, as specified in `ULrange`. (Also, note the `[[1, 1]]`. There were a bunch of brackets `{ }` cluttering up your solutions. `NDSolve` always gives lists, so it's sometimes nice just to pull out the one solution you're interested in.) You can have a look at these solutions by `Map`ping `Plot` over `s`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[NO[t] /. #], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ s
```

Next, you can define your functions pretty much as before:

```
UN1[t_] = ((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[NO[t] /. #]*(R*T))/h]) & /@ s;
j[t_] = (UN1[t] - ULrange)/(ASRRU*10000);
```

where I've replaced `NO[t] /. s` with `(NO[t] /. #) & /@ s`, and the `UL` in `j` with `ULrange`. So both `UN1` and `j` are now vector-valued functions:

```
Length /@ {UN1[t], j[t]}

(* {13, 13} *)
```

Finally, to get your points, just integrate:

```
points = Transpose@{NIntegrate[j[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau, 
                  NIntegrate[UN1[t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau};

ListPlot[points, AxesLabel -> {"j", "UN1"}]
```

[image]

The `Map` and `Do` methods ultimately produce the same output, but there is no looping structure with `Map`. The main question is what you feel comfortable working with, and where your intuition can guide you best. However, nurturing your intuition for `Map` can only be a good thing.

**Using `ParametricNDSolve` for a parameterized differential equation**

I rarely think to use `ParametricNDSolve` (so thanks @SjoerdSmit), mainly because, on some level, I don't really believe that something this useful and easy could ever actually work. But it does!

```
Clear[UL]
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{NO'[t] == 
    (1/(2*F*ASRRU))*(((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[NO[t]]*(R*T))/h]) - UL), 
  NO[0] == nO}, NO, {t, 0, 100}, UL]

(* {NO -> ParametricFunction[ <> ]} *)
```

Then you can define `UN1` and `j` as before, but with `UL` as a parameter:

```
UN1[UL_, t_] := ((R*T)/(4*F)) (Log[0.21] - Log[(nO2[Evaluate[NO[UL][t] /. sol]]*(R*T))/h])
j[UL_, t_] := (UN1[UL][t] - UL)/(ASRRU*10000)
```

Now you could just use `ParametricPlot` to get a pretty good picture of `UN1` vs. `j`:

```
ParametricPlot[{NIntegrate[j[UL, t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau, 
  NIntegrate[UN1[UL, t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau}, {UL, 0, 1.2}]
```

[image]

which nicely shows something weird going on. Be warned, though: that plot took over three minutes to plot, because it's having to do two `NIntegrates` for each point.

Alternatively, you could create some points (using `Map` again), and make a `ListLinePlot`:

```
points = {NIntegrate[j[#, t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau, 
    NIntegrate[UN1[#, t], {t, 0, tau}]/tau} & /@ Range[0, 1.2, 0.01]

ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image]

The beauty of this method (besides taking much less typing than the others) is that once you have your functions in terms of `NO` as a `ParametricFunction`, you have a whole lot more flexibility to play around with it without having to rederive everything.

Comment: Wow, @aardvark2012, that's probably the best answer i ever got in a board! Thanks a lot for your detailed reaction! I use the solution with the Map command and everything works as i desired!